# Do I need UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, transit-visas

I have a US transit visa. I am travelling from India to Jamaica. Will I need a UK transit visa as well? My flight goes from Mumbai to LHR to Miami to Montego bay.

Comment: As a tip not only for this site but in general, IT IS NOT NECESSARY TO SHOUT :).

Comment: My emphasis here was on the fact that I have a US TRANSIT visa. Does the concession apply to me?